# how to convert regexp_instr in impala

Tags: sql, impala

I used the `regexp_instr` function on Oracle like below:

```sql
substr(err_log,(regexp_instr(err_log,'regular expression')+6,3)
```

How can I convert it to Impala?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Impala String functions documentation](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/impala_string_functions.html), it supports `REGEXP_ESCAPE`, `REGEXP_EXTRACT`, `REGEXP_LIKE` and `REGEXP_REPLACE` but it does not support `REGEXP_INSTR`.

You are going to need to find another method of solving the problem without using `REGEXP_INSTR`.

One way could be to prepend `^(.*?)` to your regular expression and then use `REGEXP_EXTRACT` to match the first capturing group and you can use `LENGTH` to find the number of characters before the intended match:

```sql
SUBSTR(
  err_log,
  LENGTH(
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(
      err_log,
      '^(.*?)regular expression',
      1
    )
  ) + 6,
  3
)
```

Or, you could just use `REGEXP_EXTRACT` and if you want to match `regular expression` and then get the 6th-8th characters matched then wrap the part you want to extract in a capturing group and extract only that group:

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(err_log,'regul(ar )expression'),1)
```